# UI elements are not being updated while UIScrollView is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Touch events such as scrolling will place the run loop into NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode. In that mode it seems to be impossible updating UIView's alpha or position on screen?

I added the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate and simply set some alpha-values for another view **which is a child of my scrollview**.
The view gets only be updated after scrolling stops.

Is there some mechanism to force updates on those views?
It seems that just childs of the scrollview won't be updated.

Regards

Comment: Please show the code you are using as this is something that can be done. If I can see what you're trying to do (and how) then I'll be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollViewDidScroll:` is called continuously. This means every time view's contentOffset change, the `scrollViewDidScroll:` is called.

This code works for me:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog (@"Scroll view did scroll to %@", @(scrollView.contentOffset.x));
    self.label.alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.contentSize.width;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works now - I'm sure I did it the same way before with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code which updates the UI inside

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   //Code here to which needs to update the UI in the UI thread goes here

});
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not work in this case. Views outside of scrollview could be updated without hassle - even in `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate.